# How to list only the exquisite items with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have database "items",with all items. And I have list with keys of some of these items. How to list only those items with `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`?

Comment: Please add your Firebase structure and any related  code to your question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter`, which was specifically made for this structure. From the [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data):

> If your data is properly indexed, change your adapter initialization like so:
>
> For a `RecyclerView`, use `FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter` instead of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:
>
> ```
> new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(
>       Chat.class,
>         android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
>         ChatHolder.class,
>         keyRef, // The Firebase location containing the list of keys to be found in dataRef.
>         dataRef) //The Firebase location to watch for data changes. Each key key found at keyRef's location represents a list item in the RecyclerView.
> ```

So `keyRef` is a reference to the location with just the keys, and `dataRef` is a reference to the location with all the full items.

If you're interested in how this works under the hood, have a look at the [code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter.java)

Comment: i dont know what wrong i'm doing,but when i put FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter,i get message cannot resolve... FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter dont exist,but i'm install compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'...how its posible?